# A sentence has two verbs. Who can analyze this sentence?

Tags: verbs

"VS Code's built-in debugger helps accelerate your edit, compile and debug loop."

As you see, the sentence has two verbs, `help` and `accelerate`.

Is this sentence correct?

Who can analyze this sentence?

I think the sentence below is correct.

"VS Code's built-in debugger accelerates your edit, compile and debug loop."

Comment: Not sure about the comma. Do we understand that the edit compiles and debugs the loop? Or should "your" be "you".

Comment: @BillJ Maybe someone who is strong in programming can reply you.

Comment: The loop in question is one of editing then compiling then debugging; in other words an edit-compile-debug loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Help*, unusally, can take an infinitive complement with or without 'to':

> I helped him to carry it.
>
> I helped him carry it.
>
> I helped to carry it.
>
> I helped carry it.

So *helps accelerate* means exactly the same as *helps to accelerate*.

I can't think of another verb which behaves like this.

Comment: In this case, I don't think the word "help" really adds anything; "helps [to] accelerate" = "accelerates". The sentence would be better without it.

Comment: I think they're hedging, @JamesRandom,in case anybody claimed that it hadn't accelerated the process in a particular case.